# How do I limit the events currently being processed in a flatMap process?

Tags: limit, rate-limiting, project-reactor, flatmap

Given the following piece of code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Flux.<Long>generate(s -> s.next(System.currentTimeMillis() - start))
            .flatMap(DemoApp::delayedAction)
            .doOnNext(l -> System.out.println(l + " -- " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - start)))
            .blockLast(Duration.ofSeconds(3));
}

private static Publisher<? extends Long> delayedAction(Long l) {
    return Mono.just(l).delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
}
```

One can see from the output that a large number of events are "processed" in `delayedAction` concurrently.
In this example 256 events get generated within a few milliseconds and then wait about a second until they get emitted again.

I want to limit this number to e.g. 10, how can I do this?

The solution should be independent of what happens inside `delayedAction`

**Background**

What is really happening in delayed Action is: I do HTTP requests and starting an unlimited (or very large) amount of requests doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Can you post your solution?

Comment: @AshokKoyi https://stackoverflow.com/a/47108564/66686

Comment: You mentioned this at the end of your question "I already found the solution. But thinking this might help others. Will post an answer."

It feels like you have different answer than whats accepted. Can you please correct it

Comment: The accepted answer is my answer. I put the part you quoted into the question so others don't start typing an answer and then get frustrated when upon saving it they notice I already wrote my own. I removed the quoted part since it seems to cause confusion now and it has fulfilled its purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already a method for this: [Flux.flatMap(Function> mapper, int concurrency)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#flatMap-java.util.function.Function-int-)

From its documentation:

> The concurrency argument allows to control how many Publisher can be subscribed to and merged in parallel.

Comment: I wrote about it in a little more detail: http://blog.schauderhaft.de/2017/11/08/project-reactor-flatmap-a-closer-look/

Comment: i know this answers the question as it was asked, but the title of the question led me here for a different reason.  Concurrency isn't the same as backpressure. Concurrency is fixed - is there any way to solve this problem in a more dynamic (backpressure-ish) fashion?

Comment: The concurrency translates into backpressure, since the flatmap processor will request only more events when it has concurrency-slots available. If this doesn't answer your question you probably should post a proper one with a little more detail what you want to achieve.